# Filling gap between drywall and stairs

Tags: stairs, carpet

I have a large gap between my drywall and stairs - my question is, how much of a gap is acceptable for carpet to be applied on the stairs? I have about a 1-1x1/8 inch gap between the stair edge and the wall.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Pictures are always helpful...

Comment: thanks @SteveSh : images are added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're meant to install a **skirtboard** along the wall, cut to fit the stairs.

Here's a picture from **Building Stairs by Andy Engel** (I feel like he should hire me to market his book with how often I recommend it to people) showing installing a skirtboard onto the wall.

[image]

Comment: exactly what I needed to know - thanks!